# Font extensions and conversion

Tags: fonts, luatex, optex

In the `mtpro2` font package there are various kinds of font related files: under `type1` there are `*.pfm` and `*.pfb` files; under `tfm` some `*.tfm` files (TeX font metrics?).  There is a also a TeX file called `mtp2.tex` that can load the fonts under plain TeX (and also a LaTeX analogue).  I'd like to rewrite myself all the macros to load those fonts, rather than using the apparently complicated `mtp2.tex` file, mainly because I wish to load them in a specific way (I'd like to load them in OpTeX, in the same way in which the other math fonts are loaded).  For this specific task it would be better to have the fonts in the `*.otf` format.  How should I procede to convert them into `*.otf`?  Should I consider only the `*.pbf` files (which I can open in FontForge) or should I take into account also the other files?

Comment: optex uses the standard cm/ams-fonts fonts for math, it doesn't seem to have open type math font support (like unicode-math), so converting to otf doesn't make much sense.  Beside this: before you convert the font check if the font license allows it.

Comment: a Unicode OTF file can hold thousands of characters so to use with pdftex you need to convert subsets to a range of 256-character fonts on tfm+pfb format, however there are no particular advantages in doing the reverse conversion of converting a single pfb file to a an opentype otf file, since pdftex can not read the OTF and luatex and xetex can read both formats

Comment: @UlrikeFischer OpTeX totally has Unicode math support: https://github.com/olsak/OpTeX/blob/master/optex/base/math-unicode.opm

Comment: @HenriMenke ah interesting, I only saw the section about the preloaded fonts in the docu, but you are right later on there is something about unicode-math fonts.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  I'm going to use only luatex (since OpTeX is based upon it).  My question was more like this:  is all the font information contained in the pfb file, or is there additional font information in the other files?  In that case, how to merge the information of all files into a single otf file?

Comment: @User as I say if you convert a single OTF file to type1 (pfb) then you necessarily have to make _multiple_ fonts (or only support part of the original file. So converting from pfb to OTF only really makes sense if you are merging multiple 256-character fonts to make a single Opentype eg as the set of computer modern fonts "creatively merged" to make CM Unicode Opentype.  Just converting a singe font doesn't have any advantage especially for TeX as it will treat either version the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information about the font is in two files when Type1 font is taken into account: `file.pfb` where the outlines are defined using Bezier curves (it is binary condensed format but it can be converted to text format `.pfa`) and `file.afm` where metric of the font is declared.

The Type 1 font can include arbitrary number of characters, these charcters are referred by their standardized names (like Aacute, Rcaron etc.), no by codes. The codes of many characters in the font are not set, but application can do mapping from these names to Unicode. For example, LuaTeX (with fontloader from ConTeXt) is able to do this, so you can write for example:

```
\font\f=[cyklopr.afm]
```

(after lua font loader is loaded) and direct access to all 902 characters in the font `cyklopr.afm`+`cyklopr.pfb` is available.

But I am afraid, it will be not so simple when we are doing with math fonts. Many special features are implemented in OTF Unicode math font. The standard for Unicode math fonts in OpenType format was formulated in 2010 (cca) but PFB+AFM is much older and Math fonts are not standardized here. So the conversion PFB+AFM to OTF is not so straightforward as in text fonts (where we need only mapping from names to Unicode).

The comments above by David Carlisle are not correct, IMHO. The Type1 fonts are not 256-character fonts. But the internal encoding of typical applications used in 1990 have only 8bits per character, i.e. they can declare only 256-character encoding. TeX or PDFTeX are examples of such applications. They use 256-character TFM file in order to manipulate with fonts. And the typical single Type1 font have more TFM's with various 256-character encodings in TeX distributions. Each of such TFM must be connected to an encoding vector which is mapping between 256 codes to character names used in the Type1 font. Each of such TFM is one view throw a periscope to the whole land (to the whole Type1 font).

The first comment from Ulrike Fisher is not correct to: OpTeX implements full Unicode Math support and it recommends to use it. The 7-bit Math CM+AMS is only used in preloaded format as fonts ready to use for experiments, but not for serious typesetting. Whenever a user write something like `\fontfam[LMfonts]` the corresponding Unicode math is loaded. The reason is: it it much more simple to load only one font for math. In old days, we had to use many math families `\textfont0`, `\textfont1`, ... due to there was no single font with all math symbols and all math alphabets. But now, such Unicode math fonts exist.

I understand the OP demand: to do things more simple, no by many many TFMs periscopes. But the conversion from PFB+PFA to OTF is not straightforward in case of Math fonts unfortunately. But you can try it: read the PFB+AFM by fontforge and export it as OTF:).